# Populate data into spinner dynamically

Tags: java, android, websocket

I'm currently stuck on how I'm going to display my data to my spinner. So basically I am using Websocket to receive data and run it on my UI thread my problem is that there is no list of data showing in my spinner.

Here is my code:

```
    WayPointData = new SubscribedData<>();
    final Type WayPointType = new TypeToken<SubscribedData<WayPoint>>() {
    }.getType();


    /** an ID for the spinner **/
    spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    final SpinnerAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Pop.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spin.setAdapter(adapter);

    rosbridge = new RosbridgeListener("ws://10.24.204.231:9090");
    rosbridge.setOnDataReceivedListener(new RosbridgeMessageListener() {

        /**
         * a running thread that when the connection is made the data of the topic will serialize and deserialized java objects
         * to (and from) JSON.
         * @param msg
         */
        @Override
        public void onDataReceived(final String msg) {
            try {
                runOnUiThread(  new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            WayPointData = new Gson().fromJson(msg,WayPointType);
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                            JSONArray wayPointJsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONObject("msg").getJSONArray("waypoints");
                            for (int i = 0; i < wayPointJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject wayPointJsonObject = wayPointJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                // Parse name
                                String name = wayPointJsonObject.getString("name");
                                WayPoint wayPoint = new WayPoint();
                                wayPoint.name = name;

                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                });

                /** a msg that will display once the data is received **/
                Log.d("B9T", String.format("Received data: %s", msg));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

    spin.setAdapter(adapter);
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int p, long id) {
            WayPoint wayPoint = (WayPoint) parent.getItemAtPosition(p);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

Thanks to anyone who can help me!

Comment: and what do you have problems with?

Comment: @pskink basically displaying my data to my spinner. I'm able to receive the data but unable to display them to my spinner. I think I'm missing something in my codes.

Comment: your `SpinnerAdapter adapter` is empty: you are not adding any data to that adapter inside `onDataReceived()` method

Comment: @pskink. i see,  how will i be able to add data to the adapter if its coming from my server (rosbridge) ?

Comment: by using `ArrayAdapter#add()` method? why dont you check [ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter) official documentation?

Answer (score 0):

add array when you initing your adapter:

```
final SpinnerAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Pop.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, yourStringArray);
```

if you make changes later (will receive list from server) just setup array that you used before with new data and use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: If my string array is coming from my server (rosbridge) how will I be able to set it off without hardcoding it?

Comment: so init and set adapter only when data going to be received. Spinner wont crash without adapter, it just wont show any options.

Answer (score 0):

Here I can see you don't pass `json string` to `JSONObject` that's why your main JSON object is an empty `json object`.

You should pass the `JSON string` to the `JSONObject` parameter like below.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(msg); // here you have to add your json string in JSONObject parameter
```

Hope it helps you.